# Why does the Scala Actor implementation involve synchronized code?

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor

My understanding is that the queue based approach to concurrency can be implemented without locking. But I see lots of synchronized keywords in the Actor.scala file (looking at 2.8.1). Is it synchronized, is it necessary, would it make a difference if there was an implementation that was not synchronized?

Apparently the question wasn't clear enough: my understanding is that this can be implemented with a non-blocking queue. Why was it not done so? Why use the synchronized keyword anywhere in here? There may be a very good reason, or it might be just because that's the way it was done and it's not necessary. I was just curious which.

Comment: I think the way I worded this question was too confusing and at this point I wonder if it belongs in community wiki or just delete it or something. I didn't ask a direct technical question but rather asked for the reasoning behind some details of a certain implementation of something.

Comment: By the way, as an example, the Scalaz actor does not contain the synchronized keyword. It does use volatile inside ConcurrentLinkedQueue which qualifies as "synchronization" as oxbow talks about, but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the reactions, which you write in the "act" method, do not need to concern themselves with synchronization. Also, assuming that you do not expose the actor's state, your program will be fully thread safe.

That is **not** to say that there is no sync at all: **synchronization is absolutely necessary** [1] to implement read/write access to the actor's mailbox (i.e. the sending and receiving of messages) *and* also to ensure the actor's private state is consistent across any subsequent reacts.

This is achieved by the library itself and you, the user, need not concern yourself with how it is done. Your state is safe (you don't even need to use volatile fields) because of the JMM's *happens before* guarantees. That is, if a main-memory write happens before a sync point, then any read occurring after a sync will observe the main memory state left by the write.

---

[1] - *by "synchronization", I mean some mechanism to guarantee a happens-before relationship in the Java Memory Model. This includes the `synchronized` keyword, the `volatile` modifier and/or the `java.util.concurrent` locking primitives*

Comment: My understanding is that "synchronization is absolutely necessary" is incorrect. That a queue based concurrency can be written without locking. I just did a search for "lock-free queue concurrency" and there appears to be a number of papers on the subject. Doesn't java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue do that for example?

Comment: In theory one could make an actor library to be made entirely without synchronization, just by using a non-blocking queue and ensure state visibility through volatile r/w piggybacking.

Comment: Yes - I should have made clear that I was including "volatile" in my definition of scynchronization

Comment: Including "volatile" in your definition of synchronization avoids the purpose of the question. The question was specifically about the use of the synchronized keyword.